# Allow access to a machine behind a VPN

Tags: linux, networking

I have access to a web server running on a remote host from my machine through a VPN. I'd like to expose access to that web server using my machine so when someone accesses my IP on port 9999 then he will actually access this remote web server. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the OS of the machine?

Comment: @xenoid both are linux machines.

Comment: A solution is to run a proxy (squid or else) on your machine, that exposes port 9999. Of course this could defeat the purpose of the VPN...